# Mail Send Successful but not Recive in My inbox or spam

Tags: php, ubuntu, terminal

I am sending mail from PHP mail function and it gives me successful message but mail is not reviving in the email. I have done my gmail POP3/SMTP/IMAP settings to my OS (Ubuntu). This is my code:

```
$name = "ali";
$email ="hello";
$message = "adasdasfasf";
$from = 'From: from@gmail.com'; 
$to = 'to@gmail.com'; 
$subject = 'Customer Inquiry';
$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$headers = 'From: From: from@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: From: from@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
} else { 
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
}
```

Comment: If `mail` returns `true`, that does not mean that the message was sent successfully, it only means that the operating system / mail system on the server has accepted the message for delivery. So this is not a php problem but a problem with the server / mail delivery agent / etc.

Comment: @jeroen where is the problem how i can check and fix it

Comment: Is this a web-server or your personal development computer?

Comment: @jeroen its web-server OS ubuntu

Comment: You need to check the logs. And you will probably have more luck on http://serverfault.com/ than here.